# How do you open a LUA file that is most likely a binary?

Tags: file, lua

I have a .lua file I am triying to access to edit the code. But when I open it in VS Code the next text appears:

> "The file is not displayed in the editor because it is either binary
>   or uses an unsupported text encoding".

If I open it anyway it opens with some characters like this:

[image]

Is this file encrypted or compiled as binary? and if so is there any way I can decompile it so I can see the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you have some Lua bytecode

There are a [variety of tools](http://lua-users.org/wiki/LuaTools) to convert this to readable text, depending on what version of Lua is in use.

Comment: You should use the `.lua` extension only for Lua source code. (There doesn't seem to be a convention for naming Lua byte code files.)

Comment: @KeithThompson - `.luac`

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff: That makes sense. It would be nice of the `luac` man page mentioned it.

Comment: Both `.lua` and `.luac` file extensions are just a convention, not a standard.  Lua files could have arbitrary file extensions.  This is because of Lua was born in Linux world, where file extension means nothing.

Comment: And a Lua binary file is functionally equivalent to a Lua source file, except of course for reading and editing by humans. So, it is somewhat reasonable to use the same naming convention.